# Powers of $F$ are linearly independent in $O_P/(G)$ where $G$ and $F$ have no common component

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces, commutative-algebra

Let $F,G\in K[x,y]$ be two curves such that $F(p)=G(p)=0$. If $F,G$ have no common component then the set $\{F^n: n\in \mathbf{N}\}$ of polynomials is linearly independent in the $K$-vector space $O_p/\langle G\rangle$ where $O_p$ is the local ring of all rational functions defined at $p$.

My attempt went as follows:

If $\alpha_1 F^{n_1}+\ldots+\alpha_mF^{n_m}=0$ in $O_p/\langle G\rangle$ where $\alpha_i$'s are elements of $K$ then, $\alpha_1 F^{n_1}+\ldots+\alpha_mF^{n_m}=\frac{h}{k}$ for some $h,k\in K[x,y]$ such that $k(p)\not=0$. Hence, $\alpha_1 kF^{n_1}+\ldots+\alpha_m kF^{n_m}=hG$. Now, since $K[x]$ is a PID and hence a UFD so, $K[x,y]=K[x][y]$ is also a UFD, since the polynomial ring over a Unique factorization domain is a unique factorization domain. Let $m=\operatorname{min}_{i=1}\{n_i\}$.  Let $R$ be any prime factor of $F^m$ then, $R$ is also a prime factor of $hG$. Now, if all prime factors of $F$ do not divide $G$ then they divide $h$ and thus, $h=F^mH$ for some $H\in K[x,y]$.

but I can not complete it. Any help? And by the way, how to deduce that if $F$ and $G$ have common component then $dim_K O_p/<F,G>$ is infinite?

Comment: Perhaps try this: let $G_0$ corresponds to an irreducible component of $G$ passing through $p$. Factor the left hand side (WLOG n_1 smallest) as $kF^{n_1}(a_1+...+a_mF^{n_m-n_1})$. Then since $G_0$ is irreducible it must divide either $k$ or $F^{n_1}$. If it divides $F^{n_1}$ then you are done, otherwise if it divides $k$, then you repeat the argument until none of the components of $G$ pass through $p$ and derive a contradiction since it is equal to a multiple of $F^{n_1}$.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. It seems I needed to reverse the reasoning. Do you have ideas for the second part?

Comment: Let $H$ be their common component. Then note that you have a surjection $\mathcal{O}_p / (F,G) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_p/(H)$. So you can just argue that the latter has infinite dimension as a $k$-vector space.

Comment: @loch, I thought in this direction already but here isthe problem. To use the first part, we have to find some $K$ such that K and H have no common component and $K(p)=H(p)=0$. The easy choices like $\frac{F}{H}$ does not work since the may not vanish on $p$.

Comment: Well - WLOG you might as well assume $H$ is irreducible. Then you're just finding a different irreducible $K$ which also passes through $p$. Surely there are a lot of such polynomials!